# Forward function in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning about neural network and reading a piece of code to train the neural network with mnist data set.
In the test part of it, it defines the output variable: `y = mnist_forward.forward(x, None)` in the test function:

```
def test(mnist):
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, mnist_forward.INPUT_NODE])
        y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, mnist_forward.OUTPUT_NODE])
        y = mnist_forward.forward(x, None)

        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

        while True:
            with tf.Session() as sess:
                tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
                ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(mnist_backward.MODEL_SAVE_PATH)
                if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
                    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
                    global_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
                    accuracy_score = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})
                    print("After %s train steps, test accuracy = %g" % (global_step, accuracy_score))
                else:
                    print('No checkpoint file found')
                    return
            time.sleep(TEST_INTERVAL_SECS)
```

However, the function `mnist_forward.forward` is defined as:

```
def forward(x, regularizer):
    w1 = get_weight([INPUT_NODE, LAYER1_NODE], regularizer)
    b1 = get_bias([LAYER1_NODE])
    y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w1) + b1)

    w2 = get_weight([LAYER1_NODE, OUTPUT_NODE], regularizer)
    b2 = get_bias([OUTPUT_NODE])
    y = tf.matmul(y1, w2) + b2
    return y
```

The function `get_weight` and `get_bias` are used to generate the parameters randomly. It seems that each time the forward function is called(to predict), the parameters will be regenerated.
I just cannot understand why the function call to generate parameters should be written inside the forward function(rather than outside) and how it truly works in the prediction process of the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that each time the forward function is called(to predict), the parameters will be regenerated.

That is the big difference between Tensorflow and standard programming and can be quite puzzling at first: Tensorflow is graph based, so in this case the 'forward' function is only called ONCE to define the graph.

Then Tensorflow automatically figure out which node in the graph are needed to compute some other nodes, but it NEVER call the forward function again.

The important lines in your code to really understand what's happening inside are the following ones:

```
# Define the graph: create all variables, how to initialize them
# and how to compute the output depending on the input
# CAUTION: VARIABLE TENSORS CURRENTLY HOLD NO VALUES THEY ARE ONLY DEFINED
y = mnist_forward.forward(x, None)

...

# Add operations to the graph to compute the accuracy metric
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

...

# Initialize all variables using the initializers defined previously
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

...

# Restore all variables to saved values
# CAUTION: REPLACES ALL INITIALIZED VALUES TO THESE STORED ONES
saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)

...

# Runs the graph
accuracy_score = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})
```

> I just cannot understand why the function call to generate parameters ...

As you can see on the comments, what generates parameters is the 'tf.initialize_all_variables().run()' call, the 'forward' function simply defines HOW to initialize.